# protocol buffers : no notation for fixed size buffers?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, file-format

Since I am not getting an answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10031911/google-protocol-buffers-backward-reposition-io-head-in-the-stream-objects-provi) question I gotta prototype and check myself, as my dataset headers need to be fixed size, I need fixed size strings. So, is it possible to specify fixed size strings or byte arrays in protocol buffers ? It is not readily apparent here, and I kinda feel bad about forcing fixed size strings into the header message. --i.e, `std::string('\0', 128)`;

If not I'd rather use a `#pragma pack(1) struct header {...};`'

**edit**

Question indirectly answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10031911/google-protocol-buffers-backward-reposition-io-head-in-the-stream-objects-provi). Will answer and except

Answer (score 7):

protobuf does not have such a concept in the protocol, nor in the .proto schema language. In strings and blobs, the data is always *technically* variable length using a length prefix (which itself uses varint encoding, so even the length is variable length).

Of course, if you only ever store data of a particular length, then it will line up. Note also that since strings in protobuf are unicode using UTF-8 encoding, the length of the encoded data is *not* as simple as the number of characters (unless you are using only ASCII characters).

Answer (score 2):

This is a slight clarification to the previous answer. Protocol Buffers does **not** encode strings as UTF-8, it encodes them as regular bytes. The on-wire format would be the number of bytes consumed followed by the actual bytes. See https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding/.

While the on-wire format is always the same, protocol buffers provides two interfaces for developers to use, string and bytes, with the primary difference being that the former will generally try to provide string types to the developer where as the latter will try to provide byte types (I.e. Java would provide String for string and ByteArray for bytes).

Comment: UTF-8 is an encoding of Unicode -- it takes Unicode characters to bytes. Protobuf uses UTF-8 to get the regular bytes.

Comment: @solidsnack Thanks for the definition of unicode, although it's not relevant here. The point is that protocol buffers stores strings (or bytes) as type=2, length delimited. Protocol buffers does not care what those bytes are nor does it arbitrarily force those bytes to be UTF-8.

Comment: Consider the example at https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding#strings where it says 'The blue bytes are the UTF8 of "testing"'.

Comment: "Protocol Buffers does not encode strings as UTF-8, it encodes them as regular bytes." - there is no "regular bytes" encoding, but there is UTF-8 encoding, which specifies how to encode string into "regular bytes".

Comment: While Protocol Buffers represent strings and bytes the same way on the wire, it is still explicitly [specified](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#scalar) how `string` fields must be encoded into bytes: `A string must always contain UTF-8 encoded or 7-bit ASCII text`. Speaking another way, you can always encode strings manually into bytes and in any encoding you wish. But if you use standard Protocol Buffers generated `string` accessors for your target language, the encoding will be UTF-8/7-bit ASCII.

Comment: @AlexChe Your confusing a protocol, i.e the agreed upon wire format, and how a language binding happens to implement that. While it is true that your particular language binding may enforce such a thing it still has nothing to do with the protocol. I mention this in the second paragraph of my answer, although I suppose I could have been more explicit.

Comment: @Clarus I don't think I'm confusing it. Actually, I've already stated in my comment that strings and bytes are not distinguished in protocol. But protobuf specification from Google explicitly states that strings must be encoded in UTF-8 / 7-bit ASCII. I.e., it does not just happen, it's an explicit requirement. Therefore if you want your strings to be compatible with other protobuf binding implementations, then you must adhere to this encoding. Yes, you can encode strings manually in different encoding, but then it won't be strings by Google's definition of protobuf strings.