# Serialization of fixed size buffers

Tags: protobuf-net

I have an array of 14,400,360 structs, each struct consisting of 3 bytes of data.

```
[ProtoContract]
struct A
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    private unsafe fixed byte[3] data;
}
```

Unfortunately protobuf-net 2.0.0.668 cannot serialize fixed sized buffers, and throws an exception on serialization.  (Something like "no serializer for FixedArray")
I think the answer is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10091398/protocol-buffers-no-notation-for-fixed-size-buffers).

My current workaround is to split the fixed array into three separate bytes and fixing the layout.

```
[ProtoContract]
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 3, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
struct A
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    private byte data;

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    [FieldOffset(1)]
    private byte data1;

    [ProtoMember(3)]
    [FieldOffset(2)]
    private byte data2;
}
```

**Q:** Is there some black magic hacks or just plain tricks I'm missing out on, so I don't have to manually split the array?

When measuring the heap usage of the object containing this array, it takes up 43,201,160 bytes or just 3 bytes per struct.
The serialized file on disk takes up 72,814,584 bytes or around 5.05 bytes per struct.

**Q:** What is taking up these extra 2 bytes per struct?
I haven't tried, but maybe the serialized size could be reduced by making an array of 3*14,400,360 bytes instead? (beyond last resort)

**Edit: Correction**
The size of the serialized file was 126,246,995 bytes or 8.8 bytes per struct instead of 5.5 bytes per struct originally reported.

**Edit: Follow-up**
Using the Single Member Trick from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44050000/1087627) brought the file size down to 90,952,228 bytes or 6.3 bytes per struct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting questions. I like interesting questions!

There isn't a *perfect* way to represent this in protobuf - because the pre-defined format does not have the concept of a fixed sized data type. We have various options:

- use a field per element, but that costs a header+value per element, doubling the size (or more, for large field numbers) - not a great option (for reference, I think the reason you're seeing 5.05 is because it is skipping any zero values)
- use a length-prefixed chunk (`bytes` or `repeated packed`) - but that still costs a header plus a length plus the payload - so: 5 bytes in your case; there's also some awkward questions about what to do if we are deserializing data and it is *more* than 3 bytes, which OK shouldn't happen, but: I'm a library author and lots of things that shouldn't happen: happen
- use a single fixed size integer formatting, so: header plus 4 bytes = 5 bytes
- use a single varint integer format, so: header plus 1-4 bytes (24 bits can take 1-4 bytes, since varint is 7 bits plus continuation)

in all of these, there will also be an object wrapper around all of this which will take 2 bytes.

Given those options, I think the latter is going to be your best bet - which you could do via a single member:

```
[ProtoMember(1)] // varint by default
private uint SerializedValue {
    get { /* pack bits from the field and return */ } }
    set { /* unpack "value" into the field */ }
}
```

That's about the best of what you can do *today*; it is, however, an interesting scenario for me to consider improvements for [vFuture](http://blog.marcgravell.com/2017/05/protobuf-net-large-data-and-future.html) - maybe something that allows us to avoid the outer object overhead; essentially representing the *entire thing* as a single binary string - without the need for the inner field marker.

---

However, I wonder it the *ideal* solution here is to move up a level, so that the array / list of `A` itself can be treated as thunkable and "packed". This would mean that we essentially had something like:

```
WriteFieldHeaderWithLengthPrefix(1, WireType.String, arr.Length * 3);
foreach(var item in arr) Append(item); // writes 3 bytes
```

and:

```
var arr = new A[ReadLengthPrefix() / 3];
for(int i = 0 ; i < arr.Length; i++)
    arr[i] = Parse(item); // reads 3 bytes
```

this *isn't available* in the current code, but it **is** something that might be possible in the new code - we have the concept of custom serializers. This is certainly an area for me to explore.